# Winston http log level behaves different than info

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, winston

I am using winston to log incoming request on a `node v16` `express.js` server using following code sample (boiled down to the essentials to reproduce the behaviour).

I am not sure what is causing this difference in behaviour and I could not find any documentation relevant to it.

Package:

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"winston": "~3.3.3"
```

Server script:

```js
import express from 'express';
import winston from 'winston';

const app = express();

export const TEST_LOGGER = winston.createLogger(
{
  level: 'silly',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'test' },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.cli(),
      ),
    }),
  ],
});
TEST_LOGGER.info(`\u27F5 Starting http logging`);
TEST_LOGGER.http(`\u27F5 Starting http logging`);

app.use((req, _response, next) =>
{
  TEST_LOGGER.error(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.warn(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.info(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.verbose(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.http(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.debug(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  TEST_LOGGER.silly(`\u27F5 ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'`);
  next();
});

app.listen(8080, () =>
{
  TEST_LOGGER.info(`\u26A1 'server' launched`);
});
```

Logs when starting up the server and calling `/`:

```
info:    ⟵ Starting http logging
http:undefined⟵ Starting http logging
info:     ⚡ 'server' launched
error:   ⟵ GET '/'
warn:    ⟵ GET '/'
info:    ⟵ GET '/'
verbose: ⟵ GET '/'
http:undefined⟵ GET '/'
debug:   ⟵ GET '/'
silly:   ⟵ GET '/'
error:   ⟵ GET '/'
warn:    ⟵ GET '/'
info:    ⟵ GET '/'
verbose: ⟵ GET '/'
http:undefined⟵ GET '/'
debug:   ⟵ GET '/'
silly:   ⟵ GET '/'
error:   ⟵ GET '/'
warn:    ⟵ GET '/'
info:    ⟵ GET '/'
verbose: ⟵ GET '/'
http:undefined⟵ GET '/'
debug:   ⟵ GET '/'
silly:   ⟵ GET '/'
```

Where do those `undefined` come from?

Issue raised on GitHub: https://github.com/winstonjs/logform/issues/183

Comment: `http` in this case is just a log level, have you tried all the other log levels?

Comment: I know that, I use this library since 2 years, thats why I am so confused. `info`, `verbose` and `silly` work fine, only `http` behaves like that...

Comment: What about the other log levels?

Comment: I added all available log levels to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly the `http` log level is missing from the standard log levels in the source:

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston.js#L87

```
// Pass through the target methods onto `winston.
Object.keys(exports.config.npm.levels)
  .concat([
    'log',
    'query',
    'stream',
    'add',
    'remove',
    'clear',
    'profile',
    'startTimer',
    'handleExceptions',
    'unhandleExceptions',
    'handleRejections',
    'unhandleRejections',
    'configure',
    'child'
  ])
  .forEach(
    method => (exports[method] = (...args) => defaultLogger[method](...args))
  );
```

And seems to be coming from the package `logform`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/logform

So I would conclude that `http` isn't a valid winston log level, this should probably be raised as an issue on the winston github.

Comment: I am using this as documentation: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels
So you mean, I should use `TEST_LOGGER.log('http', \` ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'\`);` instead of `TEST_LOGGER.http(\` ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'\`);`?

Comment: @Miaucl I'm not 100% sure but that's what I would try in this situation.

Comment: I have raised an issue on github and will wait for a response there. It is currently not game-breaking but I was just curious and it might break in the future. I have checked and `TEST_LOGGER.log('http', \` ${ req.method } '${ req.originalUrl }'\`);` does not work as well.

Comment: They confirmed on github that it seems like a bug, thx @bendataclear for nudging me in that direction.  https://github.com/winstonjs/logform/issues/183#issuecomment-1168790075